# Thinking of a book cover material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

How can I make a more realistic book cover shader?

[image: viewport]

[image: close-up of a node setup]

Link to texture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXzTw.jpg

Comment: This is a rather artistic question and it would be better placed on a platform like [blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/). Anyway, improving realism is done by adding many small details with textures and avoiding sharp edges.

Comment: The nodes are not readable in the provided screenshot. Could you add a close up of the nodes?